# jquery toggle not working eventhough Console.log shows the changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

When applying toggleClass/removeClass function to the "div" - the changes are not being reflected on the HTML - but if I print the element i can see that the class was applied ?

```
$(mylement).toggleClass('myclass');
```

This is from Console by printing the element after the above statement.

```
classList: DOMTokenList[4]0: "aaa"1: "bbb"2: "ccc"3: "myClass"
```

But this does not reflect on the HTML page.

```
"myClass" just hides/shows the page.
```

I am using `SimpleModal` and this is happening once i launch the modal second time on the page.

Comment: What are the effects of "myClass" ? Or you sure that another class does not override the effect ?

Comment: Or are you sure you SimpleModel is not overwriting it again on the same element if you launch it twice=

Comment: @phtrivier - nope no other class overrides it - since its working on the first launch - it should work next time .. Good point though

Comment: @emergence - why would on the console it show the class has been applied ?